# How can i delete particular attribute and return to the home page in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

When I press the delete button nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

My html code is:

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-arrow">
 <a rel="{{ $attribute ->id }}" rel1="delete-attribute" href="javascript:" class="dropdown-item">Delete</a> 
</div>
```

```php
public function deleteAttribute($id = null) {
  ProductAttribute::where(['id'=>$id])->delete();
  return redirect()->back()->with();
}
```

Comment: my html code is:   <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-arrow">
                          <a rel="{{ $attribute ->id }}" rel1="delete-attribute" href="javascript:" class="dropdown-item">Delete</a>
                        </div>

Comment: Welcome to stack Arnab. In stead of commenting you could edit your post for the next time. Furthermore, you should supply some additional code on the routes you are using here, so we can help you better.